# Optimizing React Application - in terms of React Only [React.JS]

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

I got an interview today, where Interviewer asked me how will you improve performance of your "React Application" - in terms of react only.

He did not want any answer in terms of CSS (concatenation/minifying), JS (concatenation/minifying), Images (Image-Sprites or Using SVGs).

Now, what hint I could get was using:

- React-Memo
- useCallback hook

Now, I have actually no clue what he was talking about? Can someone help me out understanding how these 2 help optimzing in terms of React? Also, is there any other way (specifically, related in terms of React only of how to optimize performance of React-Apps)?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Does the `useCallback` documentation help? https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback

Comment: React.memo allows to "cache" what function components are rendering. Function components normally always re-render, even if their props and state are the same. Wrapped in memo, they don't do that anymore. The optimization pattern here is memoization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This article might help you: [A (Mostly) Complete Guide to React Rendering Behavior](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2020/05/blogged-answers-a-mostly-complete-guide-to-react-rendering-behavior)

From that article you will see that React will compare the `before` and `after` virtual DOM tree and look for differences. Whenever it finds one, it will schedule for re-render that whole tree which is under that tree node. I.e: A parent re-renders, all of its children will re-render too. Unless you tell React to re-use some stuff it has rendered previously and that has not changed.

[React.memo API reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo)

The way you can optimize your React app with `React.memo()` and `React.useCallback` looks something like this:

**1 - An unoptimized React app:**

See that when you click the button, `App` re-renders.

Even though nothing new is being passed to both child components, they also re-render. That's React's default behavior.

```js
function App() {
  
  console.log("Rendering App...");
  
  const [boolean,setBoolean] = React.useState(false);
  
  const someFunction = () => {
    console.log("Running someFunction...");
  }
  
  return(
    <React.Fragment>
      <Component1/>
      <Component2
        someFunction={someFunction}
      />
      <button onClick={() => setBoolean((prevState) => !prevState)}>
        Re-render App
       </button>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

const Component1 = (props) => {
  console.log("Rendering Component1...");
  return(
    <div>I am component 1</div>
  );
};

const Component2 = (props) => {
  console.log("Rendering Component2...");
  return(
    <div>I am component 2</div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

**2 - React App optimized with `React.memo()`**

`React.memo()` tells React something like that: if the new render will call that memoized component with the exact same `props` from the last render, don't render it again. 'Cause same `props` will produce same result anyway.

You will see that `Component1` has stopped re-rendering, since it keeps being called with empty `props`. But `Component2` keeps re-rendering. That's because every time you re-render `App`, a new `someFunction` variable with a new reference for the function is being created, thus, is also being changed.

And React only does a **shallow compare**. It does not look into the `someFunction` code. It only compares the reference for that variable (or a value, in case of a [primitive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive)). If any of the `props` is different than last render, it will re-render.

```js
function App() {
  
  console.log("Rendering App...");
  
  const [boolean,setBoolean] = React.useState(false);
  
  const someFunction = () => {
    console.log("Running someFunction...");
  }
  
  return(
    <React.Fragment>
      <Component1/>
      <Component2
        someFunction={someFunction}
      />
      <button onClick={() => setBoolean((prevState) => !prevState)}>
        Re-render App
       </button>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

const Component1 = React.memo((props) => {
  console.log("Rendering Component1...");
  return(
    <div>I am component 1</div>
  );
});

const Component2 = React.memo((props) => {
  console.log("Rendering Component2...");
  return(
    <div>I am component 2</div>
  );
});

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

**3 - Optimized with `React.memo()` and `React.useCallback()`**

You'll see now that only `App` re-renders. Because `useCallback` "tells" React to keep the function reference from the very first render and only change it if necessary. In this example, it will never change, because we've passed an empty array for `useCallback`.

Since it won't change, `Component2` will no longer be re-rendered every time, 'cause it will receive always the same `props`.

[useCallback API reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback)

```js
function App() {
  
  console.log("Rendering App...");
  
  const [boolean,setBoolean] = React.useState(false);
  
  const someFunction = React.useCallback(() => {
    console.log("Running someFunction...");
  },[]);
  
  return(
    <React.Fragment>
      <Component1/>
      <Component2
        someFunction={someFunction}
      />
      <button onClick={() => setBoolean((prevState) => !prevState)}>
        Re-render App
       </button>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

const Component1 = React.memo((props) => {
  console.log("Rendering Component1...");
  return(
    <div>I am component 1</div>
  );
});

const Component2 = React.memo((props) => {
  console.log("Rendering Component2...");
  return(
    <div>I am component 2</div>
  );
});

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```